# Adding an user field to a Meteor record?

Tags: meteor

Right now, my `Posts` model has a `title` and a `content` field:

**client/client.js:**

```
Meteor.subscribe('all-posts');

Template.posts.posts = function () {
  return Posts.find({});
};

Template.posts.events({
  'click input[type="button"]' : function () {
    var title = document.getElementById('title');
    var content = document.getElementById('content');

    if (title.value === '') {
      alert("Title can't be blank");
    } else if (title.value.length < 5 ) {
      alert("Title is too short!");
    } else {
      Posts.insert({
        title: title.value,
        content: content.value,
        author: userId #this show displays the id of the current user
      });

      title.value = '';
      content.value = '';
    }
  }
});
```

**app.html:**

```
      <!--headder and body-->
      <div class="span4">
        {{#if currentUser}}
          <h1>Posts</h1>
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input id="title" type="text" />
          <label for="content">Content</label>
          <textarea id="content" name="" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>

          <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="button" value="Click" class="btn" />
          </div>
        {{/if}}
      </div>

      <div class="span6">
        {{#each posts}}
          <h3>{{title}}</h3>
          <p>{{content}}</p>
          <p>{{author}}</p>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried adding an `author` field (already did `meteor add accounts-password` and `accounts-login`):

```
author: userId
```

But it just shows the id of the current user who is logged in.
I would like it to show the email of the author of the post instead.

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the email with

```
Meteor.users.findOne(userId).emails[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

@danielsvane is correct, but since your Post document's `author` field stores the `_id` of the author and not the email address, you'll need a template helper in order for the template to know how to get the email address.  Try the following:

```
// html
...
<div class='span6'>
    {{#each posts}}
        {{> postDetail}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
...

<template name="postDetail">
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <p>{{content}}</p>
    <p>{{authorEmail}}</p>
</template>

// javascript
Template.postDetail.helpers({
    // assuming the `author` field is the one storing the userId of the author
    authorEmail: function() { return Meteor.users.findOne(this.author).emails[0]; }
});
```

If it's always showing the current user and not the user who is the author of the post, then the problem lies in how you're setting the value of the `userId` variable in your event handler, which isn't code that you showed in your question.